# make django-tinyMCE right to left

Tags: django, tinymce

I have a `textarea` :

```
<textarea id="id_description" >...</textarea>
```

when I use tinymce,instead of this `textarea` I have a span (id=`id_description_parent`) ,a table (id=`id_description_tbl`) and an iframe into It (id='id_description_ifr'),I tryed many things to make it RTL:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $('#id_description_parent').addClass('text-align','right');
   $('#id_description_tbl').addClass('text-align','right');
   $('#id_description_ifr').addClass('text-align','right');
});
```

It didn't work,and I tryed this:

```
tinyMCE.init({
        directionality : "rtl"
});
```

and It didn't work.

```
tinyMCE.init({
        theme : "advanced",
        plugins : "directionality",
        theme_advanced_buttons3_add : "ltr,rtl"
});
```

and It didn't work,too.

any other suggestion?

Comment: How exactly do you apply TinyMCE on that textarea? Show full code please.

Comment: If you are using django-tinymce lib then you should set up its parameters in Django's `settings` module

Comment: I just put references to tiny-mce.js and tiny-mce-setup.js files,@ilvar as I said I've tryed many things,I wonder if U give me more clear directions.

Answer (score 1):

```
tinyMCE.init({
        mode: 'textareas',
        directionality : "rtl"
});
```

should be the correct one.
Can you show us your full html code generated on your page?

Comment: when I use mode: 'textareas' , tinymce wont work and textareas wont change!!